# postgres/psycopg2 strange timeout after 2 hrs

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

We are calling postgres using psycopg2 2.7.5  this way that we perform a query then perform some operation on data that we received and then we open new connection and perform another query and so on.

Usually the query takes between 15 s to 10 min.

Occasinally after 2 h we receive error: Python Exception : connection already closed

What may be the reason for that? Data is the same and query is the same and sometimes the same query gives results back in 3 min and sometimes it gets that timeout after 2 hrs.

I wonder if it is possible that connection is broken earlier but in python we get that information for some reason after 2 hrs?

I doubt that there are any locks on DB at the moment when we perform a query but it may be under huge load and max number of connections may be reached (not confirmed but this is an option).

What would be the best way to track down the problem? Firewall is set to 30 min timeout.

Comment: "Occasinally after 2 h we receive error: Python Exception : connection already closed"  What action in Python is throwing this error?

Answer (score 2):

> We are calling postgres using psycopg2 2.7.5 this way that we perform a query then perform some operation on data that we received and then we open new connection and perform another query and so on.

Why do you keep opening new connections?  What do you do with the old one, and when do you do it?

> I wonder if it is possible that connection is broken earlier but in python we get that information for some reason after 2 hrs?

In general, a broken connection won't be detected until you try to use it.  If you are using a connection pooler, it is possible the pool manager checks up on the connection periodically in the background.

Comment: I open connection, grab some data, close connection, the process that data for some time (like few minutes because it is computational heavy) and then repeat the operation. Is it bad?

do you know why in this python script it would try to use it exactly after 2 h?

Comment: If you close the connection immediately, then I don't see how there is anything left 2 hours later upon which an error can be thrown.  Are you sure you are not leaking them?

Comment: On postgres in logs after 2h there is information:  could not send data to client: Connection timed out

Comment: Does it report a filename and linenumber?  Can you show that part of the code?